# What is correct way to make Ajax call that sets a session/cookie in Magento?

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I am new to Magento currently I am trying to make a regular Ajax call from my JS file. To a PHP file located in a root of my project same level as app folder. However when I execute the call ajax part works fine however I always get `500 response` in my network console. If I try to call file directly like website.com/file.php it shows nothing but it should. Is there something in magento that is preventing me from doing this?

Also what is the best way to set a session and cookie in Magento, I did a small script locally that once pop up is closed it doesn't show it for the remainder of the session (and it works locally) but in Magento I can't get it.

Here is some of my code:

**Ajax**

```
// Create a session to not show pop-up
jQuery.ajax({
    url: jQuery('#baseURL').val() + "/mailchimp_controls.php",
    type: "post",
    data: { "action": "session" },
    success: function(data){
        // Do something if necessary        
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
// If Session set a session
if($_POST['action'] == "session"){
    return "Session";
    // Set value in session
    $seen = true;
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShowMailChimp($seen);
}
```

Comment: http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-use-ajax-in-your-magento-modules-themes/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this, I have create a Magento Module inside the APP/Core/Local

Where I was able to use MAGE to set sessions and cookies, if anyone is experiencing similar issues I would Google a tutorial on how to create a module inside (local) folder so that it is not overridden when you upgrade.